# Neo4j Find similarity of a string on Nodes either using JACCARD or sorensenDiceSimilarity or something similar

Tags: neo4j, similarity

I have a sequence string 'TTCTTGAAGACGAAAGGGCCTCGTGATACGCCTATTTTTATAGGTTAATGTCATGATAATAATGGTTTCT'

I have nodes with the label Sequence and property seqFull which contains a large DNA String.

Want to return the nodes and the similarity score where the similarity score is greater the .75 (75%) where the input finds a similar strings within a large sequence in Neo4J

Not looking for exact match using the term CONTAINS  but something like CONTAINS but only matches at 75% or greater

Answer (score 0):

The APOC plugin has several [text similarity functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/misc/text-functions/#text-functions-text-similarity), some of which return a percentage (as a floating point number in the range [0.0 .. 1.0]). You should Google their underlying algorithms to see if any are suitable.

For example:

```
RETURN apoc.text.levenshteinSimilarity(
  'TTCTTGAAGACGAAAGGGCCTCGTGATACGCCTATTTTTATAGGTTAATGTCATGATAATAATGGTTTCT',
  'TAATGTCATGATAATAATGGTTTCTTTCTTGAAGACGAAAGGGCCTCGTGATACGCCTATTTTTATAGGT')
```

returns:

```
0.4
```

Comment: tried google I need something like  this (psudo format) where I have a string and similariy across mulply nodes of the same label                                                                     RETURN apoc.text.levenshteinSimilarity(
  'TTCTTGAAGACGAAAGGGCCTCGTGATACGCCTATTTTTATAGGTTAATGTCATGATAATAATGGTTTCT',
  MATCH (n:Sequence {n.seqFull'})